# Getting the error [Errno 111] Connection refused, in an attempt to connect to the site mail.ru via the imaplib library

Tags: python, proxy, pythonanywhere, python-3.10, imaplib

I made a telegram bot that receives messages from the mail at the user's request mail.ru . Uploaded the project to pythonanywhere, but when trying to receive messages, the error [Errno 111] Connection refused occurs.
As far as I understand mail.ru is not in the "allowlist" list.
Is it possible to fix this error if I have a free account or I have to buy a paid subscription?

The code I am trying to run is this:

```
import imaplib
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_server)
imap.login(username, mail_pass)
imap.select(search_folder)
```

Comment: Free accounts are documented to have 'restricted outbound internet access'.  On a free plan you can only connect to the whitelisted hosts via HTTPS (not IMAPS!)

However, even with paid hosting, it's possible the mail.ru may block you.  Many email services don't allow access from cloud based locations as it is a significant source of attacks.